# Is there a way to delete or remove my apple email address completely from my apple iCloud account

Tags: icloud, email

Looking for a way to keep my apple account but remove my iCloud email address from being active or able to receive emails in any manner. Similar to how google allows you to do what is listed in this article:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177

Comment: What does keeping your Apple account entail? I think you just are asking to add a new alternate email then stop checking the original one.

Comment: I don't want to receive any email at the account from any source that might have it

Comment: You can’t do that. I’ll put an answer up  - I recommend you make a new AppleID and use that as a family organizer so you can keep purchases by put never check the mail and let it fill up unused.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the email address associated with your iCloud account to a new address.

[Change your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667) <sub>Steps below taken from Apple Support document (US) HT202667</sub>

If you no longer use the email address that's associated with your Apple ID, you can change it. You won’t lose access to your contacts, purchases, or other account information.

How to change your Apple ID to a different email address

- Go to appleid.apple.com and sign in.
- In the Account section, choose Edit.
- Choose Change Apple ID.
- Enter the email address that you want to use.
- Choose Continue.
- If you changed your Apple ID to a third-party email address, check your email for a verification code, then enter the code. If you didn't get the email, click [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201455).
- If you use services like iCloud or Messages to share with friends and colleagues, sign in to those services with your updated Apple ID.

Comment: I don’t think this is a good idea since you’re still stuck with the original mail and the new one on the account.

Comment: So ... both emails are still associated with the iCloud account even after the steps above are followed?